# CMake Error: The current directory is different than

Tags: compiling, make, cmake

I'm trying to compile the source code for Shrewsoft VPN.  The instructions say to compile the source on step 4.  However... I get this error:

```
user@ubuntu:~/Ubuntu One/Programs/ShrewSoft VPN$ sudo cmake –DQTGUI=YES –DETCDIR=/etc –DNATT=YES
CMake Error: The current CMakeCache.txt directory /home/user/Ubuntu One/Programs/ShrewSoft VPN/CMakeCache.txt is different than the directory /home/user/Programs/ShrewSoft VPN where CMakeCache.txt was created. This may result in binaries being created in the wrong place. If you are not sure, reedit the CMakeCache.txt
CMake Error: The source directory "/home/user/Ubuntu One/Programs/ShrewSoft VPN/–DNATT=YES" does not exist.
Specify --help for usage, or press the help button on the CMake GUI.
```

**Instructions:**

```
Compile the Source Code for the Shrew Soft VPN Client
1.  $> cd ~/Downloads

2.  $> tar –xzvf shrewsoft-client.tgz

Change to Download directory
$> cd ~/Downloads
Unpack the Source files.
$> tar –xzvf shrewsoft-client.tgz
3.   Change to the source directory.
     $> cd ~/Downloads/ike
4.   Run cmake.
     For GUI Installation (recommended):

$> cmake –DQTGUI=YES –DETCDIR=/etc –DNATT=YES
     For non-GUI Installation:

$> cmake -DNATT=YES
5.   Run make.
     $> make
6.   Run make install. NOTE: Run
```

Comment: You can just delete the CMakeCache.txt file and try again. The file was probably accidentally packaged in the distribution file.

Comment: Well usually you run cmake as `cmake .` or if you have a separate directory like `build` for example and what to do out-of-source-tree build then you do `cmake ..` in `build` directory. So basically this dot or two dots indicate the location of top-level CMakeLists.txt file, I didn't notice anything like this in your output though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14458805/editing-versus-deleting-cmakecache-txt-after-moving-directory